# "vagrant up" fails, and error is "invalid byte sequence in Windows-31J (ArgumentError)"

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

This is the error.  Please, does anyone know a solution?

```
sansontakeshi-no-MacBook-Air:~ yama1223xxx$ vagrant up
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:127:in `downcase': invalid byte sequence in Windows-31J (ArgumentError)
  from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in fs_real_path'
  from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:126:in `each'
  from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:126:in `block in fs_real_path'
  from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:125:in `each'
  from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:125:in `fs_real_path'
  from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:118:in `initialize'
  from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/bin/vagrant:157:in `new'
  from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/bin/vagrant:157:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this page](http://lab.unicast.ne.jp/2012/05/25/windows%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%81%A7invalid-byte-sequence-in-windows-31j%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88ruby-1-9-2/), consider setting your locale to `ja_JP.UTF-8`:

```
$ export LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
```